# Apache FTPServer Starting issue

Tags: windows-server-2003, ftp

I have Apache 2.2 Server up and running my Website on my Windows 2003 Server. I now want to give visitors the ability to upload/download data to my site.  So, I installed Apache FTPServer 1.6 but the last line of the installation said that the fTPD failed to install.

Finally after repeated attempts, the FTPD installed with no errors.

I then tried to "start" the program, but it won't start the service. I get the message "Windows could not start the Apache FTPServer on local computer."

I have tried starting the program numerous times, but with no success.  I don't have any ports open that are competing with the port that FTP wants to use. Nor, do I have a firewall in the way.  Any ideas that I could try?

Comment: It seems to me that the service is failing to start because it was not installed completely (as the first part of your question states). I would recommend you try reinstalling the application and, barring that, find a different FTP server solution.

Comment: I'm sorry Justin, but I wasn't clear in my first paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you configure logging:
http://mina.apache.org/ftpserver/logging.html
(log4j), and then look at the log on why startup fails